# Magento 2.3.3 Undefined property EmailMessage.php

Tags: error, email, magento2.3.3

I am having this issue after upgrading to magento 2.3.3 and applied the email patch they provided.
When try to send email I get:

> report.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined
>   property:Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessage\Interceptor::$zendMessage
>   in
>   /my/folder/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php
>   on line 66 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice:
>   Undefined property:
>   Magento\Framework\Mail\EmailMessage\Interceptor::$zendMessage in
>   /my/folder/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Mail/EmailMessage.php
>   on line 66 at
>   /my/folder/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"}

Line 66 has this code:

```
$this->zendMessage->setBody($mimeMessage);
```

and all the **__construct** is:

```
parent::__construct($encoding);
        $mimeMessage = new ZendMimeMessage();
        $mimeMessage->setParts($body->getParts());
        $this->zendMessage->setBody($mimeMessage);
        if ($subject) {
            $this->zendMessage->setSubject($subject);
        }
        if ($sender) {
            $this->zendMessage->setSender($sender->getEmail(), $sender->getName());
        }
        if (count($to) < 1) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Email message must have at list one addressee');
        }
        if ($to) {
            $this->zendMessage->setTo($this->convertAddressArrayToAddressList($to));
        }
        if ($replyTo) {
            $this->zendMessage->setReplyTo($this->convertAddressArrayToAddressList($replyTo));
        }
        if ($from) {
            $this->zendMessage->setFrom($this->convertAddressArrayToAddressList($from));
        }
        if ($cc) {
            $this->zendMessage->setCc($this->convertAddressArrayToAddressList($cc));
        }
        if ($bcc) {
            $this->zendMessage->setBcc($this->convertAddressArrayToAddressList($bcc));
        }
        $this->mimeMessageFactory = $mimeMessageFactory;
        $this->addressFactory = $addressFactory;
```

I have spent hours....Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

We are having the same problem since upgrading from Magento 2.3.1 to 2.3.3. We've applied all of the patches as well. Still cannot send emails using SMTP. We've tried the Mageplaze SMTP extension as well as the Kiwi Commerce SMTP extension. We use Mandrill for the SMTP provider. Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have either of you made any progress with this error? This is the only post I have found stating this issue with ZEND. I have been stuck on this issue for a month or so now.

Comment: Upgrade to 2.3.4 and check you smtp module

Comment: Please add answer in answer section comments in comment section and question in question section.

Comment: My apologies for my posting educate. I upgraded to 2.3.4 and still have issues with emailing. I have re-installed any patches at this point.